# What component do I need to add to use Live SDK 5.5 in C#?

Tags: c#, live-sdk

I want to update OneDrive text file from C#.

I downloaded and installed Live SDK v5.5, but when I try to add a component I do not see anything that looks like Live SDK in the .NET Tab.

What is the name of component I should be looking for?

This is to show that I have installed the SDK:

[image]

but I cannot find the component which I believe should be here:

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh533665.aspx

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes - I have seen that before BUT Microsoft.Live is NOT in the list, nor is it recognised when I put in code with "using Microsoft.Live;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, as with external references, you have to add them from the installation folders.

1. Go to "Browse" tab, then locate the installation folder of Live SDK 5.5 (Default is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Live\v5.5\.Net\Bin`)
   [image]
2. Select both DLL files (`Microsoft.Live.dll` and `Microsoft.Live.Web.dll`), then click "OK".
   [image]
3. Import them by `using Microsoft.Live;` (both are using same namespace)